# DirectX11 Monitor Handles

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx-11, directx-9

I'm porting over some legacy code from Dx9 to Dx11. I've managed to port over the creation of the D3D device and context fine but there's a piece of legacy code that needs to be maintained and I can't quite work out how to port it over to Dx11.

The code in question uses Win32 functions in order to get hold of a monitor's handle like so:

```
DEVMODE dm = { 0 };
dm.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
EnumDisplaySettings("\\\\.\\DISPLAY3", ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm);

POINT p = { dm.dmPosition.x, dm.dmPosition.y };
HMONITOR hMonitorGDI = MonitorFromPoint(p, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
```

It then loops through adapter monitors attached to a d3d9 device like so and looks for a matching handle:

```
unsigned int uiAdapterCount = m_p_d3d9->GetAdapterCount();
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiAdapterCount; ++i) {
    HMONITOR hMonitorD3D = m_p_d3d9->GetAdapterMonitor(i);
    if (hMonitorD3D == hMonitorGDI)
    {
        p_is->uiAdapter = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

I can't for the love of me work out how to do the equivalent in Dx11.  I've learned how to create a DXGIFactory and through that get adapter and output (monitor) information but I can't seem to find anything with regards to retrieving a monitor's handle in Dx11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IDXGIFactory::EnumAdapters` to enumerate each adapter and `IDXGIAdapter::EnumOutputs` to enumerate each adapter's outputs. Then call `IDXGIOutput::GetDesc` to get an [`DXGI_OUTPUT_DESC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173068.aspx) structure that includes a `HMONITOR` handle for the output.

You might be able to skip a step or two in your GDI example code by looking for an output with the same desktop coordinates or perhaps device name.

Comment: I can't believe I followed all those steps before asking this question and missed the Monitor variable.  What a dumbo.  Cheers for that, works like a charm :)